# How to calculate total time of multiple rows with different date and time columns in table using Laravel and mysql

Tags: mysql

[image]

I want the total time duration of highlighted dates and time for creating report of each worker total working time.

Below is my sql query:

select DATEDIFF("job_process_status.start_time", "job_process_status.end_time") as totalTime, admin_users.id as workerID, admin_users.name as workerName, count(DISTINCT jobs.id) as jobCount from `jobs_workers` left join `admin_users` on `jobs_workers`.`worker_id` = `admin_users`.`id` inner join `jobs` on `jobs_workers`.`job_id` = `jobs`.`id` inner join `job_process_status` on `jobs_workers`.`job_id` = `job_process_status`.`job_id` and `jobs_workers`.`process_id` = `job_process_status`.`process_id` group by `jobs_workers`.`worker_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, TIMESTAMP(start_date, start_time), TIMESTAMP(end_date, end_time)),
       ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY ...
```

Comment: What should I use to get the data in Hours, it is showing in timestamp now.

Comment: @p1992 *it is showing in timestamp now* No, in second. *What should I use to get the data in Hours* Divide by 3600... or use SEC_TO_TIME() function.